# GPUImage Histogram and Frame Dropping

Tags: ios, multithreading, camera, grand-central-dispatch, gpuimage

I have:

Main GPUImage preview window
GPUImage Histogram sitting on a separate GPUImageView.

```
//Adding main preview
self.previewView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
self.previewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.previewView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 552);

[self.view addSubview:self.previewView];
[self.stillCamera addTarget:self.previewView];

//Adding Histogram
self.histogramContainerView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
self.previewView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 200);
self.previewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.histogramContainerView];

self.histFilter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc] initWithHistogramType:4];
sellf.histGenerator = [[GPUImageHistogramGenerator alloc] init];
[self.histGenerator forceProcessingAtSize:histogramContainerView.sizeInPixels];
[self.stillCamera addTarget:self.histFilter];
[self.histFilter addTarget:self.histGenerator];
[self.histGenerator addTarget:self.histogramContainerView];
```

Above shows the histogram in a small container inside the main preview window. Histogram looks fine.

Issue: Once the histogram comes on, the main preview window start dropping frames considerably. This is on a iP6+. When I asked about using multithreading (GCD) with GPUImage on here, I was advised to stay away from that.

How can I resolve the frame dropping issue? Is there is a way to safely dispatch the Histogram tasks to a different thread?

Answer (score 1):

The GPUImageHistogramFilter operates using a scatter / gather operation on the GPU. All GPU-bound processing operations are already being run on a background thread, and need to have their activities coordinated, so thread-wise there isn't anything that can be done to improve this.

The histogram operation's speed is determined by how many points it has to process. The `downsamplingFactor` property causes only a fraction of the image to be processed. By default, this is 1/16th of the image, but even this can be overloaded by large images.

You can use a dummy filter before your histogram and set `-forceProcessingAtSize:` on it to rescale the image that goes into your histogram. This can significantly reduce the processing time for filters like the histogram filter.

Finally, I should note that if your stillCamera instance is a GPUImageStillCamera, what you think are dropped frames may actually be just the speed at which the camera is capturing the preview. Grabbing a video feed as a preview from a still camera is different from getting frames from a video camera instance. Still camera previews tend to update at less than 15 FPS, so you might be mistaking that for the filter slowing things down.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I did mess with downsamplingFactor, but not much luck.  I AM using GPUImageStillCamera.  Is there way to slow down the update rate of the filter (histogram in this case)?

Comment: @gizmodo - Not really. The filter works on every frame that comes into it. It shouldn't be the source of that strong a performance bottleneck, though. Try out the FilterShowcase sample application, and you'll see it running there on 30-60 FPS input sources without any dropped frames. Either too large an image size is the issue here (adjustable using an intermediate filter with -forceProcessingAtSize: set on it) or the native capture rate of the still camera preview is only giving you frames so fast.

Comment: Thanks again.  Looks like I will try the 'dummy filter' trick.